# How to Do multiple Deletion using php jquery

Tags: php

here I have a table which its data come from database (Mysql DBMS) [image: Table]

In this table I can delete  a book one by one but what I need is to delete multiple Book in once
Something like this [image]

But Actually I have no Idea How to do That Can you guys do me a favor how to do that plz I will be thankful

Comment: What is your question exactly? Just give each row a checkbox and link them to the delete button.

Comment: My question is that part actually How to link that to a delete button

Comment: Use multiple checkboxes with same name.  Then do a `foreach`

Comment: Ok Thanks Im trying to do I think I got it, I think Its somehow like multiple upload file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of checkboxes with the same name using `[]` notation, but different values, ids of records presumably:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="record_id[]" value="42" />
<input type="checkbox" name="record_id[]" value="43" />
<input type="checkbox" name="record_id[]" value="44" />
<input type="checkbox" name="record_id[]" value="45" />
```

After you select some of them, they will be passed to a server as `$_POST['record_id']` array.

Do a `foreach`:

```
foreach ($_POST['record_id'] as $id) {
     // delete record with $id here
}
```

Or implode'em, for example:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE id IN (" . implode(', ', $_POST['record_id']) . ")";
```